# Nested <li>: click event only for the deepest <li> that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

I have a bootstarp multi-level side menu (not using jQuery UI menu). Unfortunately, when I click a submenu item, all its parents are triggered as well.

This is because i have nested `<li>` elements with 'nested' id names. I need nested names in order to easily take all children content from the DB. jQuery UI `.menu()` method works well, but it is badly stylized. So I use custom sidebar with custom click() event.

How can I tell jQuery to handle only one, the deepest `<li>` element clicked?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
  <li id="m1-" class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Grandfather</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="m1-1-" class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Father</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li id="m1-1-1" ><a href="#">Son</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript** (to handle click in IDs that start with 'm', i.e. menu items)

```
$("li[id^='m']").click(function(){
  //my code to handle the click
});
```

And yeah, I see now that the 'm' preffix is not a right preffix, should be more unique like 'menu'. I will fix it later.

Comment: @ShaunakD It means that when i click on the Son, only Son will be executed, not Father and Grandfather items.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can prevent the propagation of the event from the handler so that the ancestor element's handlers will not get executed

```
$("li[id^='m']").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
  //my code to handle the click
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can stop the event to bubble up;

```
$("li[id^='m']").click(function(ev){
  //my code to handle the click
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use stopPropagation to prevent the bubbling event

```
 $("li[id^='m']").click(function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
      //my code to handle the click
    });
```

**note**: In your dom structure li nested with another li ..so it could be bubbled event when you click

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$("li[id^='m']").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```